# RDD to CSV JAVA

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm working with Apache Spark and Apache Kylin and I have to store a csv file in HDFS to be able to create with it a cube inside Kylin. The idea is to convert an RDD I obtain into a csv file and I was trying to transform my RDD into the csv file like this:

```
bookingDF.write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("hdfs://10.7.30.131:8020/tmp/hfile/e.csv");
```

but I'm always obtaining an error quite long like this and I think it is because of the field Date of the object I'm using:

```
17/01/19 14:50:24 ERROR Utils: Aborting taskscala.MatchError: Fri Dec 09 07:45:27 CET 2016 (of class java.util.Date)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)...
```

down below I attach the code of the Java Object I'm using:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Booking implements Serializable {
private String bPk;
private String type;
private String transactionId;
private Boolean revisit;
private String device;
@JsonProperty("serverTime")
private Date time;
private String trackingId;
private String browserFamily;
@JsonProperty("action")
private String measure;
private String userId;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getMeasure() {
    return measure;
}

public void setMeasure(String measure) {
    this.measure = measure;
}

public String getBrowserFamily() {
    return browserFamily;
}

public void setBrowserFamily(String browserFamily) {
    this.browserFamily = browserFamily;
}

public void setTime(Date time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTrackingId() {
    return trackingId;
}

public void setTrackingId(String trackingId) {
    this.trackingId = trackingId;
}

public Date getTime() {
    return time;
}
....
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I tried to transform the java.util.date to java.sql.date but I'm still obtaining the same error but with java.sql.date.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question though, what date object type does it want?

Comment: I realised that it doesn't accept java.date.util, therefore I used timestamp and now it is working. Can you explain how did you know it? I mean because of the line errors?? I'm learning, therefore I was not able to see which date object type it requires.

Comment: Yes I knew from the line error. It said it didn't match, which means it it looking for something specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` ?

From [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) source code:

**dateFormat:**

> specifies a string that indicates the date format to use when reading
>   dates or timestamps. 
>  Custom date formats follow the formats at
>   `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.
>  This applies to both DateType and
>   TimestampType.
>  By default, it is null which means trying to parse
>   times and date by `java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf()` and
>   `java.sql.Date.valueOf()`.

Comment: Thanks @Yaron, I had no idea that it doesn't accept java.date.util, I was researching in the direction of your answer and I used timestamp and now it is working.Now I'm obtaining other error but related with hdfs nodes I think. I will write it in other Post, I'm learning therefore always any help of the experimented colleagues is welcome :)